# Problems updating with inner join with multiple on statements

Tags: mysql, join, update

I have an `orders` table on a database that contains geographical information about the city and state that the order is from.  This includes latitude and longitude for doing haversine calculations.

I have a *new* geo-location database containing the latitude and longitude of said city states that differs slightly from my previous database.  This introduces some odd behavior because when I run haversine calculations, mileage will not be calculated correctly due to the slight differences in latitude and longitude from the previous database.

What I need to do is update the latitude and longitude on the orders table to match what occurs in the geo-location database.  This is based off the city and state that is on the order.  I am trying to update my orders table like so:

```
update ProcurementPortal.orders as orders
inner join 
ProcurementPortal.cities_extended as geo 
on orders.city = geo.city 
and orders.state = geo.state_code
set
orders.lat = geo.latitude,
orders.lon = geo.longitude
where
orders.city = geo.city
and
orders.state = geo.state_code
```

The problem I am having is that MysqlWorkbench gives me the following error.

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Is the syntax I provided correct?  Would it update the orders how I expect it to?  I can run this from the command line, but it runs for a long time and I'm not sure it's really doing what it's supposed to be doing.

I'm fairly new to mysql, so some clarification on how I could accomplish this would be wonderful.

[Output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE orders`](http://pastebin.com/duhLTEqJ) - note there are some garbage columns on this.  Needs a lot of cleaning up.  The city / state column I refer to in posted query is `oCity` and `oState`:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `action_menu` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `oCity` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `oState` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  -- many other columns
  `latitude` double(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  -- more columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `orders_company_id_foreign` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `orders_company_id_foreign` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) 
    REFERENCES `companies` (`id`) ON 
    DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=70120 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

[Output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE cities_extended`](http://pastebin.com/PP3Adj1f):

```
CREATE TABLE `cities_extended` (
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state_code` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `zip` int(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `county` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Running the query in question from the command line runs for a while, then returns the following error:

> ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

^ this might be due to the process still running.  I killed the process and it's actually going through now.  Just waiting to see if I get the same 2013 error.

Comment: The syntax is correct. But you don't have to put the condition in two places. You have them duplicated, in the `ON` and in the `WHERE` clauses. As for losing connection during query, how big are the two tables and are there indexes on them? (add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` output for both tables.)

Comment: @ypercube, the orders table is around 63k records and the geo-location table is like 363k records.  I'm not sure about indexes as I am new to mysql.    I will add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for each table.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the datatypes of the columns in `orders`? The types of the joined columns do not match.

Comment: @ypercube, I can change the types.  I didn't realize that would matter.  So if the types are different, then it won't be equal I'm guessing?

Comment: I added an answer 9assuming that you may need to do this update in the future). If it's only a one time operation, I suppose it doesn't matter if you have indexes or not. It will take longer but who cares if it's only once ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have conditions duplicated in the `ON` and the `WHERE` clause. That is not needed, the condition are only needed once, preferably in the `ON` clause as they are used for the join of the two tables. But that is not what's causing the slow execution (and the lost connections).

The reasons for being slow are three:

- you are joining a 63K with a 363K table without any index to help. That is the major issue.
- the columns used in the join do not have same type, length, character set and collation. This is another major issue, worse than the first. Even if you add indexes, but keep the same types, the indexes will not be of much help. More seriously, it's a question if you can / are allowed to change the types or the applications depend on the existing types.
- you are updating potentially the whole table. This is rather minor as the table is small, only 63K rows. We'll see if that is still a problem, **after we fix** the major issues.

The first thing that needs addressing is the types (+ lengths + charsets + collations) of the two columns. Assuming that you are allowed to change the types of the table `order`, you should change the types (both `varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL`) to match the types of the `geo` table (one `varchar(50)`, the other `char(2)`, both `CHARSET=latin1`, unknown/default collation.)

This will be tricky and perhaps error prone, so I suggest you first take a backup of the whole database, or just the table `orders`, before you attempt to change anything.

If I were you, I'd then first (before changing anything), check the data in these two columns and whether their maximum length is less than 50 and 2 respectively, to be sure that the truncation of the length will not change any valuable data.

I'd also check the collation of the `cities_extended.city` and `cities_extended.state_code` columns, it's probably the default `latin1_swedish_ci`.

(Of course these two steps above can be skipped - but only if you don't really care about the `orders` table and you can recreate it from scratch if needed.)

After everything is double checked, we can proceed with the actual changing of the types:

```
ALTER TABLE ProcurementPortal.orders
    MODIFY COLUMN oCity 
        varchar(50) 
        CHARSET 'latin1'
        -- COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci'
        DEFAULT NULL,
    MODIFY COLUMN oState 
        char(2) 
        CHARSET 'latin1' 
        -- COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci'
        DEFAULT NULL ;
```

(the `COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci'` are probably not needed, the defaults will be used, so they are commented out.)

If that goes well and there are no errors, we can proceed with the final step, which is to add the indexes:

Add two indexes, one on each table:

```
ALTER TABLE ProcurementPortal.orders
   ADD INDEX state_city_ix
       (oState, oCity) ;

ALTER TABLE ProcurementPortal.cities_extended
   ADD INDEX state_city_ix
       (state_code, city) ;
```

After that (it will take a while but you only need to do this once), you can proceed with the update statement.

If it's still taking too long, I'd consider making the update in batches (of say 1K-5K rows per time). But with so small tables, I don't think you need that.

Comment: Ok I am back at work today and will give this a shot!

Comment: how can I update in batches?  From my understanding I can only use the `row_count` param with an update.

Comment: thanks for the answer, there are more underlying issues that I have discovered, but you gave really good advice so I'm accepting it as the answer.  If you have any idea on how to solve this next issue, that would be amazing.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111286/how-can-i-rewrite-update-query-to-update-using-first-record-from-inner-join

Answer (score 2):

Try this statement.

```
UPDATE ProcurementPortal.orders
SET orders.lat = geo.latitude,
    orders.lon = geo.longitude
FROM ProcurementPortal.orders AS orders
INNER JOIN ProcurementPortal.cities_extended AS geo
       ON orders.city = geo.city
      AND orders.state = geo.state_code
```

Comment: There is an error once it hits the `FROM ProcurementPortal.orders AS orders`.  `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ProcurementPortal.orders AS orders  INNER JOIN ProcurementPortal.cities_ext' at line 4
`

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that `DOUBLE(8,2)` rounds to 2 decimal places, thereby giving a different value than `DOUBLE`.  Do not use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  Suggest you make that change before doing the UPDATEs.

Since you are talking about cities, `DOUBLE` is gross overkill and takes 16 bytes for the pair.

`DECIMAL(4,2)` for latitude and `DECIMAL(5,2)` would add up to only 5 bytes and give you about 1 mile (1.6km) resolution, probably good enough for cities.

For Businesses, these would give you about 52-foot (16m) resolution and take only 7 bytes:  `DECIMAL(6,4)` and `DECIMAL(7,4)`.

`DOUBLE` gives 3.5 nanometer resolution.

Shrinking the data size will help performance for large tables.

The lack of INDEX(state_code, city) was the performance problem.